# Intellij is using different indention within the same .vue file

Tags: vue.js, intellij-idea, vuejs2, indentation, auto-indent

In the `<template>` area Intellij is using 2 spaces for indention and for the `<script>` part it's using 4 spaces. I get errors running `npm run dev` because of the different indention.

I have set Intellij to use 4 spaces for all filetypes that I could find (not including JS or .vue). The project itself uses 2 spaces (I would like to change that).

However, now like I said it's using two different indention styles within the same file and that causes a whole lot of problems.

`Code -> Reformat code` changes the code to this style with 2 different indentions.

Any idea what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an [`.editorconfig`](https://editorconfig.org/) file in your project directory?

Comment: @YomS. Yes I do, thanks. I changed it to 4 spaces now.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you switched versions or upgraded then there might be different settings on indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you don't have **Detect and use existing file indents for editing** enabled in `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style`. If you do, when you auto-indent, it might apply the wrong settings.

Then, try reformatting the code using `Control+Alt+L` or Code -> Reformat Code.